# How is the Wii U's region locking applied?

Tags: nintendo-wii, backwards-compatibility, region-lock, wii-u

Can someone please let me know how the Wii U is region locked?

ie. what are the regions that games can be bought from for both the Wii U and how this applies to backwards compatibility for Wii games?

Comment: For instance, given I am in Australia, and have purchased an Australian Wii U (due tomorrow!), what regions could I import from for Wii U titles, and Wii titles (looking at getting The Last Story from Amazon).

Answer (score 2):

From what I could find on region locking for Wii games , Australia and Europe share the same region (PAL), so one would surmise that Nintendo would use the exact same region methodology for the Wii U, as it has not changed since the Nintendo 64.

Reference: [Wikipedia: Regional lockout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout)

Comment: I'm not unhappy with this answer (it makes definite sense), though I'd prefer a definitive source. I'm tipping that you're right that it will mirror the other Nintendo consoles though. Also, I'd like some confirmation regarding the region locking on Wii backwards compatibility.